# unable to click button after ading splash screen in android manafist

Tags: java, firebase-authentication

```js
2019-06-13 23:40:19.860 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
    
    --------- beginning of main
2019-06-13 23:40:20.181 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:40:20.181 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:40:24.231 1937-4741/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:25.940 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:26.694 1627-1627/? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.example.boc': Connection refused
2019-06-13 23:40:27.378 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:40:27.572 2416-2416/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2019-06-13 23:40:27.714 2416-2416/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2019-06-13 23:40:28.106 3356-25638/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/GeofenceHelper: Failed: remove geofences by PendingIntent
2019-06-13 23:40:28.744 1937-2091/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2019-06-13 23:40:30.639 26141-26148/? E/com.example.bo: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
2019-06-13 23:40:32.771 1733-1893/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-06-13 23:40:32.916 1733-1893/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-06-13 23:40:35.608 1937-2091/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2019-06-13 23:40:42.367 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:42.470 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:43.063 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:40:51.717 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:51.869 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:40:55.677 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:41:11.784 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:41:15.542 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:41:19.865 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-06-13 23:41:20.188 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:41:20.189 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:41:24.519 1937-4741/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:41:33.022 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:42:00.018 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:41:59.462 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:42:19.869 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-06-13 23:42:20.220 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:42:20.220 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:42:24.728 1937-4741/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:42:32.856 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:42:35.667 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:42:56.784 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:43:19.872 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-06-13 23:43:20.241 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:43:20.242 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:43:25.010 1937-2677/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:43:47.899 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:43:55.675 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:44:15.191 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:44:19.879 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-06-13 23:44:20.255 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:44:20.256 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:44:25.257 1937-2677/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:44:47.555 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:45:15.728 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:45:15.802 1937-1957/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:45:15.744 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-06-13 23:45:19.883 1749-1813/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-06-13 23:45:20.263 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:45:20.265 1860-1860/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-06-13 23:45:25.604 1937-4741/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-06-13 23:46:02.560 1937-1962/system_process E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
```

```js
package com.example.boc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWEuf.png)I am sitting a new project using firebase authentication and splash screen, when I add a splash screen to my project it does load successfully but after that, all buttons on main activity is not working, when I remove the splash screen from my manifest all buttons will back to work on main activity but there is no splash screen anymore, please see the codes .

tried to search over the internet for similar problems, didn't find any.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWEuf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFwsa.png)

```js
package com.example.boc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.animatoolib.Animatoo;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Date;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    EditText name,email,password;
    Button mRegisterbtn;
    TextView mLoginPageBack;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    String named,emailed,passworded;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        mRegisterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        mLoginPageBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        // for authentication using FirebaseAuth.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRegisterbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLoginPageBack.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==mRegisterbtn){
            UserRegister();
        }else if (v== mLoginPageBack){
        startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,login.class));
        }
    }

    private void UserRegister() {
        named = name.getText().toString().trim();
        emailed = email.getText().toString().trim();
        passworded = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(named)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailed)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passworded)){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else if (passworded.length()<6){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Passwor must be greater then 6 digit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mDialog.setMessage("Creating User please wait...");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailed,passworded).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    sendEmailVerification();
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    OnAuth(task.getResult().getUser());
                    mAuth.signOut();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"error on creating user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//Email verification code using FirebaseUser object and using isSucccessful()function.
    private void sendEmailVerification() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user!=null){
            user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Check your Email for verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void OnAuth(FirebaseUser user) {
        createAnewUser(user.getUid());
    }

    private void createAnewUser(String uid) {
        User user = BuildNewuser();
        mdatabase.child(uid).setValue(user);
    }


    private User BuildNewuser(){
        return new User(
                getDisplayName(),
                getUserEmail(),
                new Date().getTime()
        );
    }

    private String getDisplayName() {
        return named;
    }

    private String getUserEmail() {
        return emailed;
    }

}
```

```js
package com.example.boc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable delayrunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(delayrunnable, 1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide what error are you getting in logcat? Also add code from Splash scree and Main Scree.

Comment: Don't post pictures of textual content. Instead edit your question to include the actual text itself, and use the formatting options of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: ever time I try to add a code to the post the page says it is not well formatted and cannot be posted, sorry a beginner to posts here, I don't see any errors when to run on debug , it is just unclickable button ( no sound when clicking and not going to open any activity linked ).